# 'home' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module

Tags: django

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 11, 0, 'final', 1)
```

**Could you comment on this:**

```
(django11test) michael@ThinkPad:~/workspace/django11test$ python manage.py startapp home
CommandError: 'home' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

It is a newly started project:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I have always used applications called "home". And now it starts conflicting. I have already used Django 1.11 in another project. And the creation of home application didn't inflict any error messages.

Could you comment: with what does it conflict?

**ADDED LATER:**

**Tree**

```
(django11test) michael@ThinkPad:~/workspace/django11test$ tree
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── django11test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

**pip freeze**

```
(django11test) michael@ThinkPad:~/workspace/django11test$ pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
Django==1.11
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-imagekit==4.0
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
pilkit==2.0
Pillow==4.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
```

Comment: Please show the layout of your project. It sounds like you might already have a folder `home` in the project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`).

Comment: Edited the question. It's a clean project.

Comment: Does your clean project have a virtualenv? What does `pip freeze` show?

Comment: Kos, yes, virtualenv exitst. Added to the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you create an app with any other name? I know that's not what you're trying to do but may help debug...

Comment: Yes, I have created an app called "image".

Comment: Try to find from all directories given by `sys.path` for a file named `home.py` and for a directory named `home` that contains a `__init__.py`.

Comment: I was having a similar issue where deleting the project folder was not enough to fix the error however I realized the parent folder was also named the same of the project and by changing it I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to go to your python installation directory and after, go to the `Lib\site-packages` directory (e.g. `c:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\`).

Search for a folder `home` and `home-something` (e.g. `"home-0.24-py3.6.egg-info"`) and try to delete them. This has helped me.